# How do I add an auto incrementing column to an existing vertica table?

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a table that currently has the following structure

```
id, row1
(null), 232
(null), 4455
(null), 16
```

I'd like for id to be an auto incrementing primary key, as follows:

```
id, row1
1, 232
2, 4455
3, 16
```

I've read the documentation and it looks like the function that I need is `AUTO_INCREMENT` and that I can edit the table using an `ALTER TABLE` statement. However, I can't seem to get the syntax quite right. How do I go about doing this? Is it even possible with a pre-existing table?

Comment: Please mention you db?

Comment: @Nazmul [tag:vertica] is actually a database.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is the following:
**create a new sequence:**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_auto_increment START 1;
```

**create a new table:**

```
create table tab2 as select * from tab1 limit 0;
```

**insert the data:**

```
insert /*+ direct */ into tab2 
 select NEXTVAL('sequence_auto_increment'),row1 from tab1;
```

- as @Kermit mentioned the best way to do it in Vertica is to recreate the table(**once**) instead of multiple times, use the *direct* hint so you skip the **WOS** storage(**much faster**)
- As for the column constraint that @Nazmul created, i won't use it Vertica doesn't care to much about constraints, you will need to force him to insert what you want and default constraints are not the way.

Comment: One small comment, a better method to create tab2 would probably be: `create table tab2 like tab1 including projections;`.  This only works out though because he already has an id column.

Comment: Second comment, adding a column default would work as @Nazmul indicated. You just need to make sure you don't include the id column in your `INSERT` field list and it will in fact pull the next sequence. I don't prefer this way, but it does work.

Comment: @woot - the first comment is very valid and should be considered(missed that) , i totally avoid constraints on my column, this will make Vertica to extra work, i do my defaults values check during the ETL process.

Comment: I agree with you on the constraints, but I also don't consider a default on a column as a constraint.

Comment: still a constraint - it will slow my data load - i don't really care for design rules while i move data into Vertica i let this in the hands of the RDBMS that sits in front - it all about speed (Load & Query)

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your exiting data something like below

```
UPDATE table
SET id = table2.id
FROM 
(
SELECT row1, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY val) as id
FROM t1;
) as table2
where table.primaryKey = table2.primaryKey
```

Then you do alter your table using below syntax

```
-- get the value to start sequence at
SELECT MAX(id) FROM t2;

-- create the sequence
CREATE SEQUENCE seq1 START 5;

-- syntax as of 6.1
-- modify the column to add next value for future rows
ALTER TABLE t2 ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT NEXTVAL('seq1');
```

Comment: If the table is massive, an update will be very costly. A better approach will be to create a new table and do an `INSERT ... SELECT` with a sequence.

Comment: @Kermit, can't seem to get the syntax quite right...I think it should be `INSERT INTO (id) table SEQUENCE my_counting_sequence INCREMENT BY 1`, but that doesn't quite seem to be right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Auto_Increment feature,

1)Copy data to temp table

2)Recreate the base table with the column using auto increment

3)Copy back the data to for other columns

If you just want the numbers in, refer the other answer by Nazmul